# Pop-up Message "Invalid User Name or Password"

Tags: android

I trying to login and go to another new page, but the problem is, after click the button, i get the message : "Invalid User Name or Password".

I don't know what happen and also search a few example tutorial to solve my problem, but still cannot found the answer.

Here's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private EditText editTextUserName;
private EditText editTextPassword;

public static final String USER_NAME = "USERNAME";

String username;
String password;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editTextUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);
    editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
}

public void invokeLogin(View view){
    username = editTextUserName.getText().toString();
    password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();

    login(username,password);

}

private void login(final String username, String password) {

    class LoginAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        private Dialog loadingDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loadingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please wait", "Loading...");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String uname = params[0];
            String pass = params[1];

            InputStream is = null;
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", uname));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass));
            String result = null;

            try{
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                        "http://192.168.1.101/test/read_allorder.php");
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                is = entity.getContent();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                result = sb.toString();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            String s = result.trim();
            loadingDialog.dismiss();
            if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("success")){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserProfile.class);
                intent.putExtra(USER_NAME, username);
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid User Name or Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    LoginAsync la = new LoginAsync();
    la.execute(username, password);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: You should at least tell what auth utility/service you are using and share its code.

Comment: your doInBackground does not return a success and you check for a success in onPostExecute if no sucess you jump to else and it returns you Invalid User Name or Password 

find why it is not sucess in return in doInBackground

Comment: Post the relevant HTML parts of the login page the server shows.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying this -

```
  while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    result = sb.toString();
```

if result equals success then go to next activity but result can possibly anything.

But if you want to go to next activity replace

```
result = sb.toString();
```

to

```
result = "success"
```

Comment: thanks a lot your help, but the problem once i change to "success", my app can accept any username and password, means that, anyone can login in my app, why??